# Detect javascript function call in Android WebView

Tags: android, webview

I  want to do some stuff before a javascript function is being call in the webview as a result of clicking a link (the link invoke the function).

I've tried to do it with overload the "setOnTouchListener" but I always get null when I'm trying to do ((WebView)v).getHitTestResult().getExtra();

```
    mMainWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            WebView.HitTestResult hr = ((WebView)v).getHitTestResult();
            return false;
        }

    });
```

I know the name of function that is going to be called, can I do something like the "shouldOverrideUrlLoading" just for function invocation?

thanks.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29 

look that up...call the function from there?

Comment: @adi, did you ever find a solution to this? Regardless what is touched, `hr.getType() == 0` and `hr.getExtra() == null` - it's quite frustrating, I've tried it on a couple of devices with different OS versions too...

Answer (score 0):

```
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"shouldOverrideUrlLoading url: "+url);
                    if( url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:") ) {
                   //capture the url and call method you want
                        return false;
                    }

                    // Otherwise allow the OS to handle it
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    mcContext.startActivity( intent ); 
                    return true;

                }
```

Comment: what if I can't change the web page? can I inject this function?

Comment: that means you are not loading your html page on the web view ? then you don't want to use this.i edited the code.

Comment: it's not my html page. its a client. I can't change it, just load it to the webview (its on the internet).

Comment: but the "shouldOverrideUrlLoading" is not firing when pressing link element that invoke a function. I don't want to call a method, I want to do something else after the user press the link.

Comment: please post your code.if you get some error post your log also

Comment: what you mean by "I don't want to call a method, I want to do something else" ?

Comment: When the user press this link I want to open some application in the android. I dont want to call the javascript method. am I clear in my intentions?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little late for the OP, but I've found a solution which works for me. Basically, when you call `setOnTouchListener(...)` you should pass in a value of `new OnTouchListener() {...}`. Note: I'm *not* using `new View.OnTouchListener() {...}` (remove `View.` from the declaration).

I'm sure someone with better Java experience than I have could explain why this is but I guess it's something to do with the inheritance model or an explanation along those lines.